# How to delete Response header Location field in apache?

Tags: apache, http-headers, httpresponse

How to delete Response header Location field in apache?

I have already add these two lines in httpd.conf

ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod

and tried to use

Header always unset Location

But all can't worked.

I test the config by telnet 127.0.0.1 80

[root@localhost]# telnet 127.0.0.1 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
HEAD / HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 23 Feb 2015 08:33:38 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://www.example.com/
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Connection closed by foreign host.

Please help me.